# c++17 error message: "reference to non-static member function must be called" when using a macro on a vector

Tags: c++, vector, macros

I'm learning c++ and was playing around with macros. I tried defining push_back as pub, and it gave me this error:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called
  vect.pub(1);
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> vi;
#define pub push_back;

int main(){
  vi vect;
  vect.pub(1);
}
```

When I didn't use the `#define` and just wrote `push_back`, there was no error messages.

What exactly changed when I used the macro?

Comment: You have `#define pub push_back;`. You need to remove `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define pub push_back;

//...

vect.pub(1);
```

This expands to the following, which is invalid syntax due to the extra `;`.

```
vect.push_back;(1);
```

So drop the `;` and `#define pub push_back`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not put ';' for macro.

```
 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;
 typedef vector<int> vi;
 #define pub push_back

 int main(){
   vi vect;
   vect.pub(1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm learning c++ and was playing around with macros.

**Stop.** `push_back` is at most 6 extra keystrokes. Code is meant to be read by humans. You can't find `pub` in documentation, but you can find [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Similarly [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is a terrible habit. There are *loads* of names that you don't realise you've just imported into the global namespace there.

Comment: I was learning c++11 for competitive programming. *Any* time shaven is good and this code is only meant to be readable by me